# ReactJS How to add a show more/show less button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I want to add a simple "Show more" button to my Application. I have an array with data, where I want to show 3 entries as a default. When a user clicks on `show more`, the rest of the data should be rendered, and the Button should change the text to `show less`. I'm not exactly sure how to do it.

This is what I got so far:

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.cars = [
     { "name" : "Audi", "country" : "Germany"},
     { "name" : "BMW", "country" : "Germany" },
     { "name" : "Chevrolet", "country" : "USA" },
     { "name" : "Citroen", "country" : "France" },
     { "name" : "Hyundai", "country" : "South Korea" },
     { "name" : "Mercedes-Benz", "country" : "Germany" },
     { "name" : "Renault", "country" : "France" },
     { "name" : "Seat", "country" : "Spain" },
   ]

   this.isLoaded = false

  }

  showMore() {
   // show more entries
   // switch to "show less"
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="container">
     <h3>Click show more to see more data</h3>
     <div className="row">
       <h3>List of Cars</h3>
       <ul>
         {this.cars.slice(0,3).map((car, i) => <li key={i}>{car.name} - {car.country}</li>)}
       </ul>
     </div>
     <p>
      <a className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.showMore()}>Show more</a>.
     </p>
   </div>;
  }
}

React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Here is a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/bomuqitixo/1/edit?html,js,output) with the code in action

Can someone help me out?

Comment: isLoaded should be in your state. To update your rendering, call setState. You could have a "state.itemNumber" that you update to lenght when you call showMore. Inside your JSX, slice (0, state.itemNumber) and you're good

Answer (score 30):

Here is one solution. [JSBin here](http://jsbin.com/wowaluwipu/1/edit?html,js,output)

First, put all of your component data into its `state`.

```
this.state = {
  cars: [
    { "name" : "Audi", "country" : "Germany"},
    { "name" : "BMW", "country" : "Germany" },
    { "name" : "Chevrolet", "country" : "USA" },
    { "name" : "Citroen", "country" : "France" },
    { "name" : "Hyundai", "country" : "South Korea" },
    { "name" : "Mercedes-Benz", "country" : "Germany" },
    { "name" : "Renault", "country" : "France" },
    { "name" : "Seat", "country" : "Spain" },
  ],
  itemsToShow: 3,
  expanded: false
}

this.showMore = this.showMore.bind(this);
```

Let's use `itemsToShow` to know how many items to show when not expanded. We can use an `expanded` variable to change the button text based on the user's action. We're also binding `showMore` to this component so that the button knows what component's method to call when clicked.

In our render, let's change a few things, like so

```
<ul>
  {this.state.cars.slice(0, this.state.itemsToShow).map((car, i) => 
    <li key={i}>{car.name} - {car.country}</li>
  )}
</ul>
```

We're going to render from 0 to however many `itemsToShow` we have. Then we can change the button's text depending on the `expanded` value like so

```
<a className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.showMore}>
  {this.state.expanded ? (
    <span>Show less</span>
  ) : (
    <span>Show more</span>
  )}
</a>.
```

Finally, let's write the `showMore` method that actually changes the value of `itemsToShow`.

```
showMore() {
  this.state.itemsToShow === 3 ? (
    this.setState({ itemsToShow: this.state.cars.length, expanded: true })
  ) : (
    this.setState({ itemsToShow: 3, expanded: false })
  )
}
```

Comment: Very Nice! Thanks! :-)

Comment: @gihrmv very nice explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You do some things wrong. You need to understand what a state is and how react interact with it. When a state change, your render function is called again, it allow you to have dynamic rendering based on your current state.

First, initialize your state with what you want (here, I could have put only rowsToDisplay, but I guess you want to be able to update your cars as well).

You should bind this to your function showMore so when it's called, it get that "this" refers to your Component.

OnClick, showMore will be called; the function update your state. By updating it, render will be called again (remember that a change in your state call render again with your new values). This should be the only way for you to update the view.

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {cars : [
      { "name" : "Audi", "country" : "Germany"},
      { "name" : "BMW", "country" : "Germany" },
      { "name" : "Chevrolet", "country" : "USA" },
      { "name" : "Citroen", "country" : "France" },
      { "name" : "Hyundai", "country" : "South Korea" },
      { "name" : "Mercedes-Benz", "country" : "Germany" },
      { "name" : "Renault", "country" : "France" },
      { "name" : "Seat", "country" : "Spain" },
    ],    
    rowsToDisplay : 4};
    this.showMore = this.showMore.bind(this);
  }

  showMore() {
    let carLength = this.state.cars.length;
    this.setState({rowsToDisplay:carLength});
    // show more entries
    // switch to "show less"
  }
  render() {
    return <div className="container">
      <h3>Click show more to see more data</h3>
      <div className="row">
        <h3>List of Cars</h3>
        <ul>
          {this.state.cars.slice(0,this.state.rowsToDisplay).map((car, i) => <li key={i}>{car.name} - {car.country}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <p>
        <a className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.showMore}>Show more</a>.
      </p>
    </div>;
  }
}

React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Feel free to ask questions, but please read the doc first :
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      loadMore: false
    }
    this.cars = [
     { "name" : "Audi", "country" : "Germany"},
     { "name" : "BMW", "country" : "Germany" },
     { "name" : "Chevrolet", "country" : "USA" },
     { "name" : "Citroen", "country" : "France" },
     { "name" : "Hyundai", "country" : "South Korea" },
     { "name" : "Mercedes-Benz", "country" : "Germany" },
     { "name" : "Renault", "country" : "France" },
     { "name" : "Seat", "country" : "Spain" },
   ]

   this.isLoaded = false

  }

  showMore() {
   // show more entries
   // switch to "show less"
   this.setState({loadMore: true})
  }

  render() {
    const loadCount = this.state.loadMore ? this.cars.length : 3;
    return (
    <div className="container">
     <h3>Click show more to see more data</h3>
     <div className="row">
       <h3>List of Cars</h3>
       <ul>
         {this.cars.slice(0,loadCount).map((car, i) => <li key={i}>{car.name} - {car.country}</li>)}
       </ul>
     </div>
     <p>
      <a> className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.showMore()}>Show more</a>
     </p>
   </div>
   );
  }
}

React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```

use this.setState() to reRender the component!