# Show more/Show less text

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I'm new to React I want to make show more/show less button. When the text is not expanded the browser should show only 3 lines. I found a solution with array ([ReactJS How to add a show more/show less button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370592/reactjs-how-to-add-a-show-more-show-less-button)), but I want to do it with text. My question is how to show exactly 3 lines of text and expand it on button click.

Comment: if someone will have same problem, use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lines-ellipsis

Comment: Well. Instead of number of lines it should be character limit as device lines may change based on device. If you want to set it based on character limit, check out my answer here. 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67073016/5782438

Answer (score 3):

You can use `react-lines-ellipsis` for the same by using `npm install --save react-lines-ellipsis`

```
  <LinesEllipsis
    text='long long text'
    maxLine='3'
    ellipsis='...'
    trimRight
    basedOn='letters'
  />
```

[for more information](https://npm.runkit.com/react-lines-ellipsis)

Answer (score 1):

@IncrediblePony

I am using React. You don't need javascript etc. You can use in React add remove class. You can use like this.

```
.hide{
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  height: 3.6em; 
  background-color: #363636;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
}

class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        shown: true,
    };

    render() {      
        return (
            <div><h2 className={this.state.shown ? '' : 'hide'}>
It will coming long text here</h2><button onClick={() => this.setState({ shown: !this.state.shown })}>Show more</button></div>
        )
    }
}

const mountNode = document.getElementById('app');
React.render(<App />, mountNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  height: 3.6em;
  background-color: #363636;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
}
```

Comment: yes - this would hide the text, but then you have to manipulate the DOM through javascript or jQuery after the fact. If you use react you can bind a function to the individual div and let that component handle its state.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple example here: https://codepen.io/joshbivens/pen/LNLKor?editors=1010

I edited this to behave in such a way that the button toggles a long piece of text like so:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        shown: true,
    };

    render() {      
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>{
                        this.state.shown ? 
                        "Bacon ipsum dolor amet brisket pancetta leberkas ..." : 
                        "Bacon ipsum dolor amet brisket pancetta leberkas, landjaeger shank tail capicola tri-tip meatball. Shankle pig jowl tail doner corned beef ham hock biltong pork belly burgdoggen pancetta. Cupim pork loin tongue pastrami. Ball tip corned beef strip steak salami, porchetta chicken pork chop shoulder capicola. Ball tip swine strip steak, ground round tail rump porchetta beef biltong pork chop sausage meatloaf drumstick. Short loin corned beef short ribs buffalo chislic sausage."
                    }</h2>
                <button onClick={() => this.setState({ shown: !this.state.shown })}>Show more</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mountNode = document.getElementById('app');
React.render(<App />, mountNode);
```

This is the basic principle behind it. You can modify your code to suit your needs with this I hope.

Comment: it's code duplication, I have a lot of divs, where I want to show text

Comment: Okay - I'm gonna say this as gently as possible. You need to think OUTSIDE the example I have given you. The text string should OBVIOUSLY come from a data source and should be called as such in the code. I could not within 5mins of your post come up with a datasource, application code and deployment system for you to ctrl-c ctrl-v into your code... I gave you an example on how to deal with long pieces of text. If the state of shown is toggled by clicking the text or a link or a button then show more text. Just give it two seconds of thought before responding....

Comment: @IncrediblePony chill tf out

Comment: @userlkjsflkdsvm - a very helpful comment indeed....