# Limitation for Charachters to show in div's

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, character

I have an issue right now. I have a text that user can see(Description for Item),
and I want it to show only first 60 characters. I have tried different solutions from stackoverflow, but nothing helped me. Thank you.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import "./productItem.css";



const ItemDescribtion = () =>
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad";

const ProductItem = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Card className="product--item">
                <Card.Text>
                    <ItemDescribtion />
                </Card.Text>
            </Card>
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: Without a functional version of your cod`e showing the problem, it's difficult to know what your limitations are, but have you tried text-overflow: ellipsis;`?

Comment: @RichDeBrouke I dont have any function in this component right now, thats why im asking what it should look like. Tried `ellipsis` but it didnt work:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple.

Declare a state for handling description which will have following fields.

1. **flag**: to indicate if full description is shown or not
2. **text**: description text to show
3. **message**: text indicating ***show more***/***show less***

`const[descriptionText,setDescriptionText] = useState({flag:false, text:'', message:''});`

Declare a maximum-char-limit like this.
`const DESCRIPTION_CHAR_LIMIT = 60;`

Here is my function to display description. It displays full or some part of description according to max-char-limit.
[image]

Here is my function to toggle Show more/Show less
`const toggleDescription = () => setDescription(fullDescription);`

Here is my code for description box. Don't worry about the tag names. They are just my styled components.

I hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to limit the text in your cards and your user can see the full text by clicking on the card or something, then you could use text-overflow: ellipsis;. If you need to show the full answer in the card, then you could use JavaScript as suggested by @knigalye.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>
    .card-text {
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```